# Angular x detect when an @Input set

Tags: angular

I am beginner to angular so I need some help if you guys dont mind. I am in a situation where component A changes component B's @Input value. The ngOnChanges function doesn't fire because I not really changed the value. I set the value of it like to 4 from 4. So I set it to the same. In this case there was no change detection because the value did not changed. On the other hand I need to know when component A does something like this with component B's @Input. I have tried the getter setter functions but it worked the same or very similar. Could you help me with an example about this please? Thanks your answers and time in advance :)

Code example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybd2qx

Comment: You need to clarify your question. may be with some code

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What concrete problem are you trying to solve? Why do you care to know in B that you have affected a value to a field in A if the value hasn't changed at all?

Comment: I recreated this situation and added to the original question.

Comment: So why is it a problem for me and why I want to know when a set happend? I created a custom select box. It is a component (B), the number is the selected option what is a negative number by default. There is a script what cancels a form where this custom select box is included a few times 4-5. I want to change it to the negative number again and catch this thing when happens even if it did not changed yet.

Comment: OK. Still not sure why changing from -1 to -1 should change anything in your custom component. But if the goal is not to pass a property, but instead to call a method of your B component, then do that. For example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z4teqr?file=app%2FBcomponent%2FB.component.html. Or use a service to emit an event from A, and listen to it in B.

Comment: Thanks JB this solved my problem :)

Comment: @BálintRéthy You can use `$watch` on that which will fire the event whenever the value got changed